# Automatically create a token for admin in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am looking for a method to create, automatically, a token with `rest_framework.authtoken.models.Token` when admin logins into admin panel.

I can set-up it manually by adding the Token, but I would prefer to have it automatically created at login and destroyed at logout.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a token before login operation you can override django authentication backend like below example:

```py
class TokenCreatingBackend(BaseBackend):
    def authenticate(self, request, username, password, **kwargs):
        user = super().authenticate(request, username=None, password=None, **kwargs)
        # your token generation here!
```

and add this line to your **settings.py**

```py
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS=['path.to.your.TokenCreatingBackend']
```

To delete the token you can override logout view:

```py
def my_logout_view(request):

    user = getattr(request, "user", None)
    if not getattr(user, "is_authenticated", True):
        user = None
    # destroy token
    user_logged_out.send(sender=user.__class__, request=request, user=user)
    if hasattr(request, "user"):
        from django.contrib.auth.models import AnonymousUser

        request.user = AnonymousUser()
```

And set urls to hook it up:

```py
...
   path('account/logout/', 'path.to.my_logout_view', name='logout'),
   path('admin/logout/', 'path.to.my_logout_view', name='logout')
...
```

If you want to create token right after [authentication signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/auth/#module-django.contrib.auth.signals):

```py
from django.contrib.auth.signals import user_logged_in, user_logged_out


def create_token(sender, user, request, **kwargs):
    pass # create token

def destroy_token(sender, user, request, **kwargs):
    pass # destroy token

user_logged_in.connect(create_token)
user_logged_out.connect(destroy_token)
```

Comment: And this can be done only when admins logins into admin panel?

Comment: It runs on every login.You can seperate  wsgi processes with different settings for admin and integrate them with a reverse proxy.